# Облачные сервера и git

Tags: git, github, unreal-engine-5

Доброго времени суток всем, пилим игру с другом в ue5, возникла необходимость работать над проектом совместно.
В ue5 есть аддон(multy user editor) из коробки для совместной работы в реальном времени, но минус заключается в том, что один из нас должен стать хостом и если мы будем поотдельности что-то допиливать мы не сможем подключиться к совместной разработке из-за того, что в конечном итоге наши версии проекта будут разные.
Из возможных решений это:

1. Работать в одно время постоянно подключаюсь друг к другу.
2. Держать два компа включёнными 24/7, чтобы независимо от времени они были законекченными,что тоже не выход ибо это не удобно.
3. Использовать git и gitlab, но мы упирается в огранку в 10гб,что не позволяет нам разгулятся, так как сейвы и прочие файлы могут занимать 5гб и более уже через пару дней разработки.
4. Использовать git и выделенный сервер, что стоит не дёшево для инди разрабов.
5. Использовать git с облачным хранилищем.

Суть вопроса заключается в том можем ли мы использовать git с облачным хранилищем TeraBox, так как они предоставляют 1тбайт бесплатно и если да, то как?

Comment: попробуйте отделить код и ресурсы проекта. Всё тяжелое будут хранить в облачном хранилище, а код проекта в gitlab/github

Comment: 6. Использовать git и не держать два компа включенными 24/7, отправляя изменения по мере возможностей.